# The Wikipedia Search for Typeahead sample code - EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend

Tags: ng-bootstrap

When following ng-bootstrap Wikipedia Search sample code for Typeahead  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead, I get "EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend!".

It worked well for Simple Typeahead example. But it didn't work for Wikipedia search example.

[See here for detailed description of the error and steps.](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1228)

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to say what is going on without having access to a minimal reproduce scenario but I *suspect* that you were missing import for the `JsonpModule`.

In any case here is a minimal plunker that demonstrates fully working example that you are mentioning: http://plnkr.co/edit/kUE4VJclfmtpzb8OfVhk?p=preview. You might want to compare your setup with the one in this working plunk.